# dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.

Tags: update-manager, usb-modem

How do I install a Huawei E1752, since my cursor doesnt work. how do I use the command line to install the modem and ensure that I complete the update.

Answer (score 2):

Boot into Ubuntu , after reaching to login-screen , don't login directly.

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> and then it will open a command line Ubuntu . There type your username and password to login.

Then type

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

then restart your PC.